# How to put an image at the left side of text without putting the image into css

Tags: html, css

My scenario is to achieve a section in web page looks like this: 
[image]

I am okay to use image and I am okay to use css. But as I am working in Salesforce, it is quite hard to put images into css file or section which means I can't use css code like this:

```css
.wStatusCompleted {
    background: #DBFBD6 url(../img/wizardCompleted.png) 20px 16px no-repeat;    
}
```

Everything else is fine but putting the url of image in the css will result in resource not found. So I am trying to achieve it via html way and here is what I tried:

```html
<div style="float:left">
    <img src="{!$Resource.wizardCompleted}"/>
</div>
<div>
    <span style="font-size:18px;margin-bottom:20px;"> Completed</span>
    <br />
    <span>Well done, you have successfully completed this request and received payment.</span>
</div>
```

I have tried a couple of things and this is the closest one but still not what I want. Any suggestions?

**Edit**

To answer the comment, the above html will result in an image as shown below:

[image]

Comment: `this is the closest one but still not what I want.` so what do you want?

Comment: Which other language are you using to set the img src?

Comment: @Mouser I am using javascript and jquery but this section is static so probably that is not needed. The server side is controlled by Salesforce so I have no control over that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be floating both of your divs not just the one wrapping the image:

```
<div style="float:left;">
   <img src="http://www.placecage.com/50/50"/>
</div>
<div style="float:left;">
    <span style="font-size:18px;margin-bottom:20px;"> Completed</span><br/>
    <span>Well done, you have successfully completed this request and received payment.</span>
</div>
```

Be sure to clear your floats using `overflow:hidden` or a clearfix on a parent element or (in the event that there is no parent) by adding an empty element set to `clear:both`. This appeared to be working but your second container was actually sitting behind the image because of the `float:left`

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/a2kjtuet/)

To align the text in the middle just use `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left` and set `vertical-align:middle;` for both of them:

[**NEW FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/a2kjtuet/2/)

Comment: And not to forget to add `overflow: hidden;` to the wrapping element to fix the clearing.

Comment: Thank you for this. But there is one more question. The text is aligned to the top of the image. Is there a way I can make it align to the centre?

Answer (score 1):

You can try also display:inline to make the img behave like a text element.

```
<img src="http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/985/affel/128/tick.png" style="display:inline-block;"/>
<div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; margin-top:2em;">
  <span style="font-size:18px;margin-bottom:20px;">Completed</span><br/>
  <span>Well done, you have successfully completed this request and received payment.</span>
</div>
```

[Fiddle to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/qn2sgywb/)

Comment: Thank you for both your answers. Since jmore's answer is earlier and more comprehensive, I mark it as best answer. And plus 1 for this.